# Amazon s3: Image link is dead on Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Sending HTML email from the rails app makes image url dead. I build with **AWS S3** and **AWS SES**.

**views/news_mailer.html.erb**

```
<div class="icon">
  <%= image_tag @item.image.to_s %>
</div>
```

**mailers/news_mailer.rb**

```
class NewsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def all_notify(item)
    @item = item

    mail(
      subject: @item.title,
      to: "test@example.com",
    )
  end
end
```

I wonder I have to fix S3 settings...

image link is like this

```
https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/jhtnRHXmN3Z-Mh0r-3Dildvviner2BBXGyqOcjIRvUTL7s3s2gNlucBVi25nfQze1GSspvhbpCLygjLYqge-yn4mP7jPLpZhBmFUtEbVTFqg8V23v-1bvqN14SCfRVPg_pPtfjEk69r-2rajeeJyH19Pi-8PzCE1tUv4uyPIAyzKa-Ijc-fd_56w5Nc5U3Yl0MQrGe5AXc3d3LeQd8I0vQKtp494SOYPIiSCeE2WsmGwkRts2BX7EfOaKAhZX99bdVkYOjoCM183hb8A6fLFpFSK-CxcfChIrjgKvDLbXwuBQT89PWTFBYGpaGEBPer3eNnuIKfZa8ZtkBG6UI6IsHcDfVi93yqQ_oGvM2SD2h-inkuy4_Oaa9Yjx-qgHPAlUunzA3Hi2frTErjNh1flwmz62iWhuysSwTYLQ95hisu3fuUViuC_o5awVCUrzBDPMeATLcctZObWtbGmcD5LYv9tWrnz3dyBZdlxizU2jGLimAyaLauQDbmCX6B-EVxnkLg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://example.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/product/image/154/marubatsu-quiz-generater.jpg?X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Date=20190614T232723Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJIMUKNPRWGBOPJMQ/20190614/ap-northeast-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=53134c41b3adf17720a2e4bd14c08b7831d4877591e4c9704dbfcee9834960c1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your image link is the actual link you are using in the email...

Looks like the URL might be incorrect, error returned from AWS is:
`The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`

The amazon error shows: `<Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<Bucket>example</Bucket>`

The endpoint you used is `https://example.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com` but it should be `https://example.s3.amazonaws.com` (according to error), which doesnt include the region.

You can make either your buckets images public (or the bucket itself), and use the public url, or you can save some money and keep bucket private but allow access through cloudfront (CDN) which has other benefits to it (speed, cache, lower cost).

Comment: Thanks you so much. I'll try to fix it!